# raise NetworkError(f"Unknown error in HTTP implementation: {repr(exc)}") from exc. Unknown error in HTTP implementation: Event loop is closed

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I can't figure out what's wrong in my code:

```
import threading
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder
import asyncio
import time

botApp = ApplicationBuilder().token(token="******:******").build()

def main():
    * computation stuff *  
    while True
        asyncio.run(send_msg()) * send result of computention 2 times* 
        time.sleep(5)


async def send_msg():
    print("sending")
    await botApp.bot.sendMessage(
        chat_id="********",
        text='example',
        parse_mode= 'markdown'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=main()).start
    botApp.run_polling()
```

that raise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 130, in _call_sslobject_method
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 888, in read
  **  v = self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLWantReadError: The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:2607)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 274, in _request_wrapper
    code, payload = await self.do_request(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/request/_httpxrequest.py", line 199, in do_request
    res = await self._client.request(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1533, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1620, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1648, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1685, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1722, in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 353, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 253, in handle_async_request
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 237, in handle_async_request
    response = await connection.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 90, in handle_async_request
    return await self._connection.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 144, in handle_async_request
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 112, in handle_async_request
    status, headers = await self._receive_response(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 229, in _receive_response
    event = await self._receive_stream_event(request, stream_id)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 260, in _receive_stream_event
    await self._receive_events(request, stream_id)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 281, in _receive_events
    events = await self._read_incoming_data(request)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 341, in _read_incoming_data
    raise exc
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 327, in _read_incoming_data
    data = await self._network_stream.read(self.READ_NUM_BYTES, timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/httpcore/backends/asyncio.py", line 34, in read
    return await self._stream.receive(max_bytes=max_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 195, in receive
    data = await self._call_sslobject_method(self._ssl_object.read, max_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 137, in _call_sslobject_method
    data = await self.transport_stream.receive()
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1264, in receive
    self._transport.resume_reading()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 798, in resume_reading
    self._add_reader(self._sock_fd, self._read_ready)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 744, in _add_reader
    self._loop._add_reader(fd, callback, *args)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 256, in _add_reader
    self._check_closed()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
   ** raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 26, in <module>
    threading.Thread(target=main())
  File "./test.py", line 12, in main
    asyncio.run(send_msg())
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "./test.py", line 18, in send_msg
    await botApp.bot.sendMessage(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 2598, in send_message
    return await super().send_message(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 331, in decorator
    result = await func(*args, **kwargs)  # skipcq: PYL-E1102
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 760, in send_message
    return await self._send_message(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 488, in _send_message
    result = await super()._send_message(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 512, in _send_message
    result = await self._post(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 419, in _post
    return await self._do_post(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/_extbot.py", line 306, in _do_post
    return await super()._do_post(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/_bot.py", line 450, in _do_post
    return await request.post(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 165, in post
    result = await self._request_wrapper(
  File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/telegram/request/_baserequest.py", line 290, in _request_wrapper
    **raise NetworkError(f"Unknown error in HTTP implementation: {repr(exc)}") from exc
telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')**
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

I wanted to create a main function to do some computational stuff every 5 seconds and advise me sending a message using a telegram bot... For this reason I created a thread to run the main function while the main thread run the telegram API

Comment: I recommend to use the [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-–-JobQueue) (built-in feature of `python-telegram-bot`) instead of using threading + `time.sleep`. At the very least you can use `asyncio.sleep` + `asyncio.create_task` to not mix threading with asyncio.